# Installing cPanel on a load-balanced environment?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, webserver, aws, cpanel

I have a cluster set up on AWS Ubuntu under 2 load balancers. Is there a way to install cPanel on the servers so that it will still work under the load balancer? I know cPanel doesn't currently have true load-balancing support, but was wondering if anyone has found a work-around for it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://autom8n.com/ plugin for cPanel to create a cluster and use the LB or the plugin itself does Load balancing using DNS